# How to get data from AVAudioplayer bit by bit

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, touch

I am new to iOS development. Now i'm doing application like talking tom. this application has to record screen and audio simultaneously. I'm able to record with AVAudioRecorder but i want the data which playing by AVAudioPlayer bit by bit, because some times user might start record from middle from the audio clip. I know about AVAudioPlayer's data property, but with that i'm getting all the data in data format. I want data bit by bit while playing.